# How does SMTPSVC on Hotmail set hostname in SMTP header?

Tags: exchange, smtp, spam-prevention, hotmail

The daily spam to my Hotmail-account today contained a message with a forged sender addresssuspicious enough for me to check the SMTP header.

The only "Received" entry was:

```
Received: from grogrol ([192.184.84.162]) by COL0-MC4-F51.Col0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Mon, 12 May 2014 13:43:36 -0700
```

What kind of hostname is "grogol" ? A DNS lookup does not find any name. Could it be a local hostname known to the SMTPSVC server?

The message ID was:

```
Message-Id: <E1Wjx4R-0007I1-Kz@grogrol>
```

Is that where SMTPSVC got "grogol" from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do specifically with Hotmail, or really SMTPSVC even.

The canonical form for the Received header goes like:

```
Received: from HELO-NAME (RDNS-NAME [IP]) by SERVER-NAME with PROTOCOL; DATETIME
```

(It is formally defined in [RFC 5321](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt), section 4.4, and called *trace information*.)

So `grogrol` would appear to be the name the remote server used in the `HELO` or `EHLO` SMTP command. That agrees with it being used in the host-part of the message ID as well.

The `RDNS-NAME` part of the received header is not included if the IP address of the connecting host does not have a reserve name record in DNS, which it does not.

It follows that the only part about the host specification that you can actually rely on (and the only part you *should* rely on, generally speaking) is the IP address of the connecting host, which in your particular case is given as 192.184.84.162.